# Contact and Case records created from Pre-chat form(Snap-in) are not attached to Live Chat transcript record

Tags: api, liveagent, service-cloud-console

1. I am using [snap-in chat feature](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_snap-ins_chat.htm) released couple of releases ago.
2. Unlike the old Live Agent, Snap-in lets admin customize what information to be collected from the pre-chat form and what records to be created as shown in the below screenshot:
   [image]
3. For the customer, who wants to chat with agent, shows the below pre-chat form as expected:
   [image]

so far, so good but the contact and case records created using the information collected from pre-chat form are not attached to the live chat transcript record and agent has to do manually.

There is a similar question asked about [Adding chat transcript to case in Live Agent](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/57058/adding-chat-transcript-to-case-in-live-agent) but how do I use the solution suggested in that answer. Snap-in does not give any option to write any custom code.

I feel lost with this and any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Is your Snap-In implementation for a community, public or otherwise? Or an external website?

Comment: This was for a public community.

Comment: I am currently looking through documentation to find an answer to this as well (for a public community). We are running into an issue where we are not even seeing a Case getting created. Did you have to do anything additional to have the Case created?

Comment: To follow up here, we had a trigger blocking the Case being created. That is now resolved and the Case is connecting to the Live Agent Transcript automatically. Are you using an out of the box pre-chat form or a custom Lightning Component?

Comment: Out of box pre-chat form. I implemented this in my last projet and moved on to another project now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to round this out for others searching for a solution, in the Winter '19 release there is a feature to add a code snippet to the pre-chat in your community.  Here's a link to the feature in the release notes

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_snapins_snippet_settings.htm

Here are some examples of code you can add to the snippet to carry out various tasks such as attaching to the chat transcript.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.snapins_web_dev.meta/snapins_web_dev/snapins_web_prechat_code_examples.htm